Azure Function not triggered by Service Bus Topic with Firewall rules despite whitelisting app
Edit: The solution, which is actually in the doc of service bus network page, is to have a virtual network with a subnet delegation to Microsoft.web/ServerFarm, and to connect both the service bus and app to that network/subnet.
Azure Function App triggered by Service Bus Topic Message v2 trigger ( documentation about it here )
This works fine when there are no firewall rules on the service bus, but with firewall rule, even whitelisting all the function IPs, the function doesn't get triggered at all (no delivery attempt from sb subscription, no request/logs on function)
My trigger:
@app.function_name(name="consume_event")
@app.service_bus_topic_trigger(
    arg_name="message",
    topic_name=TOPIC_NAME,
    connection="SERVICE_BUS_CONN_STR", # App setting containing connection string of access policy of the topic
    subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
)
def consume_event(message: func.ServiceBusMessage):

TOPIC_NAME and SUBSCRIPTION_NAME are env variable with the name of their respective resource
"SERVICE_BUS_CONN_STR" is the name of the env variable (app setting) containing the connection string - which is the Primary connection string of a listen only access key created on the topic of the service bus
The IPs I have whitelisted on the service bus are all the IPs found for my Function App
I also enabled "Allow Trusted Microsoft Services" on the networking section of the service bus namespace
Why is the function still not being triggered?

Have tried with private endpoint connection?

No, I just whitelist all the ip from my app function, and enable "allow trusted microsoft services to bypass firewall"

I have followed below steps to trigger the Azure Function by Service Bus Topic with Firewall rules.
Created a Service Bus Topic Trigger.
Code Snippet:
app = func.FunctionApp()
        
@app.service_bus_topic_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", subscription_name="servicebussubscriptionName", topic_name="servicebustopicname",
                               connection="ServiceBusConnectionString") 
def servicebus_topic_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Topic trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString":"Service_Bus_Connection_String"
  }
}

Enable Selected Networks under ServiceBus=>Settings=>Networking.
Add client IP address to the list of allowed addresses under Firewall section:

Send the messages in Service Bus Topic:

Able to trigger the function through Service Bus Topic with Firewalls rules.
Output:
C:\Users\uname\pyfunc>func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-11-15T10:12:18.276Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        servicebus_topic_trigger: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-15T10:12:23.192Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-15T10:12:57.965Z] Executing 'Functions.servicebus_topic_trigger' (Reason='(null)', Id=d4e52f60-cde4-4ec0-80b8-5c579a9bdbfe)
[2024-11-15T10:12:57.971Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 26be26f0b96a47c3a8f3acba01a26069, SequenceNumber: 3, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-11-15T10:12:57.3740000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-11-15T10:13:57.4050000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2024-11-15T10:12:58.233Z] Python ServiceBus Topic trigger processed a message: Welcome to Service Bus
[2024-11-15T10:12:58.346Z] Executed 'Functions.servicebus_topic_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=d4e52f60-cde4-4ec0-80b8-5c579a9bdbfe, Duration=404ms)

Portal:


This works when running locally, when the app is deployed, this won't work.
The solution, which is actually in the doc of service bus network page, is to have a virtual network with a subnet delegation to Microsoft.web/ServerFarm, and to connect both the service bus and app to that network/subnet.

You are right. You have to Enable Network with access with Virtual network to make it work in portal.
